# How do I make a copy of a branch for testing rebase?

Tags: git, branch, rebase, squash

I've done this before by creating a clone and doing the rebase in the clone, but I suspect I could do it safely on a separate branch.

I have a feature branch `feat-x` with about 25 commits on it. I'd like to (safely) squash several of these together.

(I say "safely" because the first couple of times I squashed I didn't get it right -- but was working in a clone so just threw it away until I figured out the right incantation.)

What sequence of commands will give me `feat-x-exp` that is a copy of `feat-x` so I can experiment with squashing without disturbing `feat-x`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you want to just do:

```
git checkout -b feat-x-exp feat-x
```

This checks out a copy of `feat-x` that you can experiment with. Once you've moved off the `feat-x` branch, you rebase commands won't affect the original branch (so long as you avoid the two argument form that's a shortcut for checking out before a rebase).

If you mess up, you can go back to the state of the original branch with:

```
git reset --hard feat-x
```

If your experiment is successful, you can move `feat-x` to match `feat-x-exp` and remove the experimental branch:

```
git checkout feat-x
git reset --hard feat-x-exp
git branch -d feat-x-exp
```